# Hammer.js - how to allow side scrolling with swipe up/down

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js with swipe gestures. I have a home page that is a full width/height page. When the user swipes up the home page moves up and a long horizontal scrolling page comes into view. If the user swipes back down I want the home page to come back into view.

[image]

It seems as though I can either have:

a) Allow swipe down and swipe back up - with no side scrolling

or

b) Allow swipe down and side scrolling - but no swipe back up

Has anyone had a similar issue and found a work around?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out on my own in the end. I created an absolute positioned box in my large scroll area this was full width and included the style: touch-action: pan-x !important; This overwrites the touch-action: pan-x, pan-y; that Hammer adds. I then called Hammer on this object and it works!